# CMake can not determine linker language for target when compiling assembly files for RISC-V

Tags: assembly, gcc, cmake, riscv

I'm trying to build a RISC-V project but I get the following error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/riscv32-unknown-elf.gcc-12.1.0/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/riscv32-unknown-elf.gcc-12.1.0/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf-g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "test.elf".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: test.elf
-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

This is a project made of 2 assembly files: `startup.s` and `main.s`. If I change `main.s` to be a `main.c` with just an empty `main` function, my `cmake` command works.

The command I use to build my project is just:

```
mkdir build
cd build 
cmake ..
```

And I get the error explained above. My code is attached below:

### Dir. tree

```
.
├── toolchain-riscv.cmake
├── src
│   ├── startup.s
│   ├── main.s
│   ├── main.c
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── linker.ld
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

As you can see, there are 2 main files. This is just to check the difference between using `main.c` and `main.s`. With `main.c`, my `cmake` command works, wuth `main.s`, it produces the error mentioned above.

### toolchain-riscv.cmake

```
# Set cross compilation information
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR riscv)

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")

# GCC toolchain prefix
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX "/opt/riscv32-unknown-elf.gcc-12.1.0/bin/riscv32-unknown-elf")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)

# TODO this should be the assembler, but ${CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS} are
# actually gcc flags, therefore they won't work with as
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)

set(CMAKE_AR ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-ar)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-objcopy)
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-objdump)

# TODO These are actually gcc flags. The assembler should be
# used and these flags replaced
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -march=rv32g -mabi=ilp32 -static -mcmodel=medany -fvisibility=hidden -nostdlib -nostartfiles -g -O0")
set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -march=rv32g -mabi=ilp32 -static -mcmodel=medany -fvisibility=hidden -nostdlib -nostartfiles -g -O0")


set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS "")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS "")

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS true)
```

### ./CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.1)

include(toolchain-riscv.cmake)

project(test)

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf STATIC)

target_link_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf
    PRIVATE
        -T${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/linker.ld
)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

### src/CMakeLists.txt

```
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf
    PRIVATE
        main.s
        startup.s
)
```

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `cmake` doesn't enable the `ASM` language by default. The above needs to add either `enable_language(ASM)` or `project(test ASM)`.